# How do I calculate a % complete on tasks which are due before a certain date with rollup function in MS Project

Tags: ms-project

For a project that I am managing in MS Project I would like to have a % complete of tasks that need to be finished before Q2.

E.g. I have one task with 10 sub tasks.
5 of these sub tasks have a due date of June and % complete of 75% and the other 5 have a due date of December and a % complete of 0%.
In one column on the summary level I have the % complete of all the 10 tasks (37.5%) and in the other column only the summary of the 5 tasks due in June (75%)

Comment: Are you asking how MSProject calculates it or something else?  Are you measuring % complete based on duration, hours, dollars, or physical?

Comment: I calculate it on physical % complete but want to have it rolling up in 2 columns 1 for all subtasks and 1 for only selected sub tasks.